# Define several values for a gitlab ci variable depending of the environment

Tags: gitlab-ci

Maybe I didn't understand something, I want the gitlab CI to know the domain of the environment for which it is building. The way I am doing it right now is that I defined 5 times the same ENV_DOMAIN variable, setting a different value for each of my env, using this window:

[image]

This looks weird to me, isn't there a simpler way to say "ENV_DOMAIN is a variable which should have this value in for this environment"?